# Get next html element with selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following html body that gives a list of elements. Please keep in mind that this html is just for demonstration. In the actual body, the list contains more than 20 properties.

```
<dl>
   <dt class="sc-ellipsis">Merk</dt>
   <dd>
       <a href="https://www.autoscout24.nl/auto/audi/">Audi</a>
   </dd>
   <dt class="sc-ellipsis">Model</dt>
   <dd>
       <a href="/lst/audi/q3">Q3</a>
   </dd> ....more properties like that
</dl>
```

I would like to get the words: **Audi** and **Q3**

I can simply do this in Selenium:

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('dd')[0].text # to get Audi
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('dd')[1].text # to get Q3
```

**BUT** sometimes some of the elements might be missing, therefore I can not rely on the position mentioned above. For example if **Audi** is missing, then this:

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('dd')[0].text # now it returns Q3
```

returns **Q3**. One common pattern is that **Audi** will always follow *Merk* and **Q3** will always follow *Model* . Namely, if *Merk* is not in the html body **Audi** won't be either. What I tried is to find the very next html element of Merk:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/[(@class="sc-ellipsis") and (text()="Merk")]/following-sibling::dd')))[0].text
```

But this returns an empty list which means it didn't find **Audi**. Does anyone know how to get the next element of Merk (or Model or whatever comes next in the list) ?
I can create a catcher myself, so if Merk is not part of the list, then don't try to get the next element.

Comment: I think your XPath is looking for the following sibling with a p tag, when in reality you want to look for the following sibling with a dd tag.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will return the text of the dd following the dt with text "Merk"

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.autoscout24.nl/aanbod/audi-q3-sportback-pro-line-business-35-tfsi-110-kw-150-p-benzine-zilver-757ef256-c967-457b-8db1-4cb8b287c311?cldtidx=19')
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//dt[text()="Merk"]/following-sibling::dd')
print(elem.text)
```

After examining your code, it seems the only issue was that you were not stating the tag type of the first tag. Either use wildcard, or dt.

```
'.//*[(@class="sc-ellipsis") and (text()="Merk")]/following-sibling::dd'
'.//dt[(@class="sc-ellipsis") and (text()="Merk")]/following-sibling::dd'
```

Comment: The class element is not the problem. You did not reference a tag type for the first tag, or specify wildcard. So Xpath did not know what type of tag to look for in the first place before finding its sibling